# Implementing Naïve Bayes algorithm in MATLAB - Need some guidance

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, gaussian

I have a Binary classification problem that I need to do in MATLAB. There are two classes and the training data and testing data problems are from two classes and they are 2d coordinates drawn from Gaussian distributions.

The samples are 2D points and they are something like these (1000 samples for class A and 1000 samples for class B):
I am just posting some of them here:

5.867766 3.843014
5.019520 2.874257
1.787476 4.483156
4.494783 3.551501
1.212243 5.949315
2.216728 4.126151
2.864502 3.139245
1.532942 6.669650
6.569531 5.032038
2.552391 5.753817
2.610070 4.251235
1.943493 4.326230
1.617939 4.948345

If a new test data comes in, how should I classify the test sample?

P(Class/TestPoint) is proportional to P(TestPoint/Class) * (ProbabilityOfClass).

I am not sure of how we compute the P(Sample/Class) variable for the 2D coordinates given. Right now, I am using the formula

P(Coordinates/Class) = (Coordinates- mean for that class) / standard deviation of points in that class).

However, I am not getting very good test results with this. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the good method, however the formula is not correct, look at the [multivariate gaussian distribution article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution):

P(TestPoint|Class)=
[image],

where [image] is the determinant of A.

```
 Sigma = classPoint*classPoint';
 mu = mean(classPoint,2);
 proba = 1/((2*pi)^(2/2)*det(Sigma)^(1/2))*...
         exp(-1/2*(testPoint-mu)*inv(Sigma)*(testPoint-mu)');
```

In your case, since they are as many points in both class, P(class)=1/2

Comment: These are how the training samples are:

http://tinypic.com/r/nplvo0/5

There are around 2000 training samples (1000 from each class). I chose 100 random samples from each class, trained the Naive Bayes classifier with it and tried to predict the class label of the rest.
This is the result I get.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2j1n7f9&s=5

Evidently, I am wrong. I'll try to use the formula posted by Oli and post the result here.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/684lt4/5

This is the points classification I see with the formula. Thanks a lot :) I don't know how I missed that I could apply the pdf of a Gaussian distribution to get the probability of a point belonging to a class.

Comment: The misclassified points have reduced greatly. Thank you again.

Comment: The results on your picture seems to be right. I think it's working now.

Comment: I cant seem to upvote, I am a new user here and it says I need 15 reuptation points :(

Comment: That's funny, I thought that the owner of the question always could. Anyway, good luck. Machine Learning is a very exciting topic.

Comment: Thank you. Machine learning is indeed exciting. Text categorization with Naive Bayes is what I am interested in. But, I am still starting.

Comment: @Oli, The Sigma, is it just the `cov(sample of class 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your formula is correctly applied, another issue could be the derivation of features from your data points. Your problem might not be suited for a linear classifier.

Comment: No, he said that the two distributions are gaussian, in that case, the optimal separator is linear.